# Fechar todas aplicações em segundo plano menos o meu aplicativo

Tags: android

Estou pensando num aplicativo que tem como objetivo fechar todas as outras aplicações que estão rodando em segundo plano, porem, deixar somente o meu aplicativo executando. Alguem tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro creio que seria interessante explicar um pouco como funciona a arquitetura Android.

Os aplicativos desenvolvidos para Android são escritos em Java, o que significa que serão compilados e executados dentro de JVM no sistema. Na prática isso significa que todo e qualquer aplicativo roda dentro de uma Sandbox, ou seja, não possuí acesso à outras aplicações e nem à recursos do sistema.
Para utilizar recursos do sistema, você deve declarar essa intenção e caso o usuário deseje o sistema libera uma porta para acesso à esse recurso.

No caso você não consegue interagir diretamente com uma aplicação, o que você consegue fazer é declarar "Intenções" e caso a outra aplicação comporte, executará essa "Intenção", de outra forma, a única outra interação é efetivamente transferir o usuário para outro APP. Nestas duas possibilidades você consegue controlar o ciclo de vida do seu Intent (Intenção), e pode terminá-lo quando quiser.

Agora para aplicações que não foram lançadas por você, elas estarão em outra Sandbox e não terão interface com sua Aplicação, sendo assim, o ciclo de vida delas será controlada pelo Android, que faz uma gerência de quando uma aplicação é escondida ou totalmente destruída de acordo com a necessidade do sistema.

Então creio que o único modo de fechar todas as outras aplicações seja rooteando o celular e executar um comando Linux do seu aplicativo, e mesmo assim, corre um risco enorme de quebrar o sistema.

Se a sua aplicação for consumir muitos recursos, o Android automaticamente fechará outros aplicativos para direcionar os recursos para a aplicação em que o usuário está interagindo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Lucas então nao tem como usar uma intent que aciona o botão do android: (fechar aplicaçoes)?

Comment: Não, por questões de segurança você só pode interagir com outros aplicativos que você declarar e que o usuário autorizar. O único que pode encerrar processos de outros aplicativos é o OS. Você só poderá fazer isso se estiver rooteado

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade tem como fazer isso, inclusive existem varios aplicativos que o fazem. Infelizmente não sei como funciona para te ajudar, apenas corrijo o colega acima.

Comment: As aplicações que "fecham" os aplicativos normalmente mandam um Broadcast de restart, daí como os outros aplicativos não foram visualizados não ocupam quase nada de memória, ficam em Stand-by, mas se você olhar no gerenciador verá que continuam abertos.

Comment: Assim, eu ja vi aplicativos semelhantes que fazer isso, inclusive em eventos tecnologicos. Dai fiquei com essa curiosidade. Se eu aprender daqui pra la posto aqui